# MySQL way to dynamically store new userIDs in an array and retrieve

Tags: mysql

I want to store the IDs of users who click a button to join an event so that I can know who has joined an event and such. Preferably in an array I was hoping but I learned that I cannot create arrays in MySQL. So How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: put them in a table, like anything else.. a [properly normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) table.

Comment: yes thank you, this was it, I didnt know that there was no other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table of `EventUsers [EventId], [UserId]`

```
CREATE TABLE EventUsers (
EventId INT(10) NOT NULL,
UserId INT(10) NOT NULL
)
```

When user x selects event y,

```
INSERT INTO EventUsers (EventId, UserId) VALUES (y, x)
```

Comment: So there will be many rows containing different userIDs of the same Event ID... I see, thanks for your help

Comment: @Ayudh That's how RDBMS works traditionally. If you really want, you can write few lines of code to store a comma separated string (for example) in UserId column, but I'll not recommend that!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I shall mark yours as the answer, I have achieved what I set out to do. If you will not recommend using a comma separated string than I will heed your advice so it will not be necessary, thank you.